# Comparator vs op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, comparator

I was trying to find the difference between a normal op-amp and a comparator.

I saw one [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb3F9-ghv58&t=778s) where they mention that an op-amp without feedback is a comparator.

I have a few op-amps which have a feedback but act as comparators.

[image]

Is the definition correct? What am I missing to understand this?

Comment: "But I have a few op-amp which have a feedback which acts as a comparator." - can you give more details, like which op-amp and what the feedback circuit is?

Comment: Edited the schematic. And we can consider the schmitt trigger (op-amp) as a comparator right? In the basic schmitt trigger circuit, we do have the feedback, right? So, whether to call it as a comparator or an op-amp

Comment: A comparator *can* have positive feedback. We do that to implement hysteresis.

Comment: So, is the video tutorial wrong when it says that a comparator is an op-amp without feedback?

Comment: The video (haven't watched it) is probably being simplistic and missing one key word; the basic comparator is indeed a differential amplifier without *negative* feedback.

Comment: So can you clarify if you are especially meaning ICs that are either op-amps or comparators? Because you can surely build op-amps and comparators with discrete components, by using transistors or thermionic valves. And in a tight spot, you can use an unbuffered inverter as an inverting amplifier too.

Comment: in my mind (feeble), a comparator is 0 or 1, an op amp is 0-1.

Answer (score 2):

The TLV1805 is a comparator, and the feedback is being used to create hysteresis.

You can use an op-amp like a comparator, but there are caveats. See the following
TI publications for more details:

*Op Amp and Comparators – Don’t Confuse Them! - SLOA067*

http://encon.fke.utm.my/nikd/latest/sloa067.pdf

*TI Precision Labs - Comparators: Pros and cons of using an op-amp as a comparator*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iURc2C_QHbU

Answer (score 1):

You can use some op-amps as comparators, and they may be superior in some ways to typical comparators. Chips designed to be comparators are usually designed to be fast, not particularly high gain and offset voltage and drift is not too important.

Chips designed as op-amps are usually designed to be compensated (stable with feedback) for a gain of 1 or some other number. If they are not internally compensated, they have internal nodes brought out so that external compensation can be added. Internal compensation makes the amplifier *slow* when used as a comparator. You may find cheaper, lower power, more accurate op-amps which can be useful as comparators.

Most comparators cannot be compensated so that they are stable enough when used as amplifiers, so it's less practical to go the other way (the LM393 is an exception, but it still makes a pretty horrible amplifier).

Some op-amps cannot tolerate large differential voltages (more than a few hundred mV) or large current flows between the inputs so that disqualifies them for use in many comparator applications.

But there's nothing stopping you from using 1/4 of an LM324 (for example) as a comparator if it has adequate performance for  your application. It would be dumb to add another chip and the associated power consumption if it wasn't necessary. If you're switching a relay with the comparator output, for example, the comparator speed is of no concern.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But could you tell me whether the video is wrong when it mentions that a comparator is an op-amp without feedback? If its right, how and why? If its wrong, could you please help me understand when to use op-amp or a comparator?

Comment: Your example shows a comparator with positive feedback. An op-amp can be used as a comparator with positive or no feedback. With negative feedback it's usually intended as an amplifier.

Comment: wouldnt an opamp abused as comparator draw excessive input current through its differential diodes ?

Comment: @tobalt Very few op-amps have differential diodes. Only bipolar super-beta types (not CMOS input, JFET input, ordinary bipolar input). So avoid those (eg. LM308). And if it works reliably and is within specs it's hardly "abuse". The front ends of LM393 (comparator) and LM324 (op-amp) are almost identical except for bias current.

Comment: hmm my experience told me that most BJT opamps do have them. but checking again seems to confirm you. Does that mean that most newer opamps from eg. TI or Analog are superbeta ones ?

Comment: @tobalt bipolar types, probably. I doubt you'd be tempted to use them as a comparator. Part of a quad CMOS type, or LM324, more likely.

Answer (score 0):

A true comparator is faster than an op amp acting as one and I think I'm correct in saying that the common mode input range of a true comparator is usually higher than that of an op amp acting as one.

An op amp or true comparator operating in open loop can both be called comparators but quite often these comparators would be given some hysteresis (two threshold levels) by adding positive feedback. I would then refer to the overall circuits as schmitt triggers rather than comparators.